# Cannot resolve symbol 'TestUnit' in maven project

Tags: java, maven, junit

I'm trying to learn JUnit Testing currently. I want to test first custom 'TestUnit' class but IDE tells me that Cannot resolve symbol 'TestUnit'. What I should do to fix this error?

[image]

TestUnit class:

```
package test.lessons.purejava;

import org.junit.Test;

import static org.junit.Assert.assertEquals;

public class TestUnit {

    @Test
        public void testAdd(){
        String string = "Test unit works";
        assertEquals("Test unit works", string);
    }

    @Test
    public void concatTest(){
        Concatenation concatenation = new Concatenation();
        String result = concatenation.concat("Hello", " World");
        assertEquals("Hello World", result);
    }
}
```

and pom.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
     xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
     xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

<groupId>test.lessons</groupId>
<artifactId>purejava</artifactId>
<version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
<packaging>jar</packaging>

<dependencies>
    <!--&lt;!&ndash; 
 https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.microsoft.sqlserver/mssql-jdbc 
 &ndash;&gt;-->
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/junit/junit -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>junit</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
        <version>4.12</version>
        <!--<scope>test</scope>-->
    </dependency>

</dependencies>
</project>
```

Comment: you should remove the entire main method. Unit tests are not supposed to be called through a main method

Comment: this code copied from tutorialspoint.com, this code is from there.

Comment: https://www.tutorialspoint.com/junit/junit_environment_setup.htm

Comment: then what i do?

Comment: If you want to learn junit, take a look at any of these https://www.baeldung.com/junit
https://www.mkyong.com/tutorials/junit-tutorials/